# Ho to map through mui icons to redirect to url like github/project-url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

*//i have a separate project file of the projectlist as an array with object, which have the necessary links that i need to map through.
//I just need some help with adding them into the github icon and when a user clicks they can navigate through to the appropriate links from the projectlist. I realise i need to use Object.entries(obj).map(). However, none of the methods i have attempted so far have worked. I am new to react so this may be simpler than I am actually making it. All help is appreciated.*

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { ProjectList } from "../helpers/ProjectList";
import GitHubIcon from "@mui/icons-material/GitHub";
import LanguageIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Language";
import "../styles/ProjectDisplay.css";

//useParams returns an object key/value pairs of the dynamic params from the current URL that were matched by the <Route path>

function ProjectDisplay() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const project = ProjectList[id];

  return (
    <div className="project">
      <h1>{project.name}</h1>
      <img src={project.image} alt="portfolio-projects" />
      <p>
        <b>Skills:</b>
        {project.skill}
      </p>

      <GitHubIcon />

      <LanguageIcon />
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProjectDisplay; 

*//projectlist below*

export const ProjectList = [
  {
    name: "SquareSpace Website Homage",
    image: squarespace,
    skill: "HTML, CSS, JavaScript",
    github: "https://github.com/LouisNzavi/Portoflio-Website",
    website: "https://mysquarespacehomage.netlify.app/",
  },
  {
    name: "HarryPorter theme TODO CRUD app",
    image: harryporter,
    skill: "HTML, CSS, JavaScript",
    github: "https://github.com/LouisNzavi/TO-DO-APP",
    website: "https://gabriellatodoapp.netlify.app/",
  },
  {
    name: "Restaurant Reservation System",
    image: reservation,
    skill: "React, Redux Toolkit and TypeScript",
    github:
      "https://github.com/LouisNzavi/RestaurantReservation---reduxToolkit-Typescrpt",
  },
  {
    name: "Deposit/Withdraw system",
    image: depositWithdraw,
    skill: "React, JavaScript, Redux: reducers/store/action-creators",
    github: "https://github.com/LouisNzavi/React-with-redux-deposit-withdraw-",
  },

  {
    name: "Four-card landing page feature",
    image: fourcardfeature,
    skill: "HTML, CSS, JavaScript",
    github: "https://github.com/LouisNzavi/Four-card-feature-design-file",
  },
  {
    name: "Vancouver Sleep Clinc website",
    image: vancouver,
    skill: "HTML, CSS",
    github: "https://github.com/LouisNzavi/Vancouver-Sleep-Clinc-PROJ",
  },
  {
    name: "Intro component with SignUp form",
    image: signupForm,
    skill: "HTML, CSS, JavaScript",
    github: "https://github.com/LouisNzavi/Intro-Signup-form",
  },
];
```

Comment: can you share file for ProjectList

Comment: @Manish Sencha i have added the ProjectList also by editing the original question

Answer (score 0):

I think this is you want to do

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { ProjectList } from "../helpers/ProjectList";
import GitHubIcon from "@mui/icons-material/GitHub";
import LanguageIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Language";
import "../styles/ProjectDisplay.css";

//useParams returns an object key/value pairs of the dynamic params from the current URL that were matched by the <Route path>

function ProjectDisplay() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const project = ProjectList[id];

  return (
<React.Fragment>
{ProjectList.map((project, index) =>
    <div key={index} className="project">
      <h1>{project.name}</h1>
      <img src={project.image} alt="portfolio-projects" />
      <p>
        <b>Skills:</b>
        {project.skill}
      </p>
      <a href={project.github} rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
        <GitHubIcon />
      </a>
      <LanguageIcon />
    </div>
)}
</React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default ProjectDisplay;
```

You can map your array to the component which will return an array of project components then you can directly render it. I am assuming you are using import to use images in `project.name`.

Comment: Hi, thank you I managed to resolve the issue using a different method but will also try this :)